# Wholesale pricing

Tags: cart, discount, customer-group, tierprice

I am working on an e-commerce store that sells paintings(qty limited to 1 per product). My client wants me to design kind of a separate page where customers are able to buy paintings in bulk, with the a few rules applied:

- Minimum purchase is U$ 10,000 per cart
- Price of the products shown needs to be discounted by 30%: now here is the tricky part. We have 2 currencies in store, USD and IDR. The displayed wholesale price needs to be 30% off the IDR price, BUT shown in USD.

Please provide me with hints and instruction on how to approach this goal. Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

I would create a second store view (Wholesale)

Then update attributes (price) in Catalog>Manage Products on store view (Wholesale) using -30%

Afterwards use Default Display Currency as USD on store view (Wholesale) and finally use Sales > Minimum order ammount on store view (Wholesale)

If you need more info, feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks for the help! This is almost perfect, now the only problem I have is when accessing wholesale.mydomain.com, the prices shown are prices of the retail store.

Comment: Did you changed product prices on Wholesale view? And cleaned cache afterwards? Are the prices in correct amounts but wrong currency?